# highcharts not to fill the width

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to draw a stock graph. It start with zero data, then add one data point per minute. after whole day, it fill with 240 data points.

The x axis is fix length, and designed for the whole 240 data points. When the data points have not grow to 240 yet, we want the corresponding part of chart of the missed data to be empty.

I've check the highcharts API, and cannot find options to do that. It looks like all the highcharts demo are filled the chart with data available.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you set `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`.

For example if you have two points in your data:

```
// January 1st 2015, 00:00 and 00:01
data : [[1420070400000, 3], [1420070460000, 7]]
```

Then you'd set the min and max to allow space for all the points that will eventually be added:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 1420070400000,
    max: 1420070400000 + 86400000 // 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 added
}
```

As in [this demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/s8953zq9/), which has two points and space for the entire day.

Comment: the 2 point case look work, but if I change it to 3 data points,  the line fill the whole x-axis again. example here : http://jsfiddle.net/s8953zq9/1/

Comment: Right. I assumed you use Highstock. Is that right? If so, you want to add `xAxis.ordinal: false`, like here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8953zq9/2/)